# Location based automatic mobile silent action

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

For an Android app, I want to implement **location-based feature** that **silences users's mobile device automatically when they enter a given location**.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Tasker is separate app , but I want that feature to implementation in my.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be helpful. 
https://github.com/Preston-Landers/QuietPlaces

Comment: Link you have sent ,that is an Android app ? .
I should use it as reference and build my app using that code ! .

Answer (score 1):

You can use  Geo-fencing for this.

Geofencing combines awareness of the user's current location with awareness of the user's proximity to locations that may be of interest. To mark a location of interest, you specify its latitude and longitude. To adjust the proximity for the location, you add a radius. The latitude, longitude, and radius define a geofence, creating a circular area, or fence, around the location of interest.

Please visit : https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html